# ROUNDED_CORNERS not working in google cast sdk

Tags: javascript, streaming, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

In my receiver.js I am styling the captions through the TextTrackStyle. I could do most of the things except for the windowType ROUNDED_CORNERS. Nothing happens when I modify the property windowRoundedCornerRadius, I tried from 10 to 1000. Does anybody have a solution?

```
let textTrackStyle = new cast.framework.messages.TextTrackStyle();
textTrackStyle.fontFamily = "Nunito-Medium";
textTrackStyle.fontScale = 1;
textTrackStyle.backgroundColor = "#000000B3"; // Black with 70% opacity
textTrackStyle.windowType = "ROUNDED_CORNERS";
textTrackStyle.windowRoundedCornerRadius = 10;

playerManager.addEventListener(cast.framework.events.EventType.PLAYER_LOAD_COMPLETE, () => {
  let textTracksManager = playerManager.getTextTracksManager();
  textTracksManager.setTextTrackStyle(textTrackStyle);
});
```

I am following this documentation: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages.TextTrackStyle

Excepted: Rounded Corners in captions window

Got: Squared Corners

Answer (score 0):

The docs show an attribute called `windowCornerRadius`. You're adding `Rounded` to the property so it's not actually updating with the correct value.

[image: screenshot of docs]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am following this documentation to implement the receiver.js. It says to use windowRoundedCornerRadius and windowType:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages.TextTrackStyle

Comment: Bummer, I was guess I happened to find my way the Google Play SDK on accident. Is the type being set correctly?

Comment: My fault I didn't specified the SDK! So, if I understood your question, the doc says windowRoundedCornerRadius as number and windowType reference the property cast.framework.messages.TextTrackWindowType, which is a string with the possible values as None, Normal, Rounded_Corners